# The cast to value type 'double' failed because the materialized value is null - AVERAGE

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a query getting the average, of all gathered values.
The table works as an grade average motor for students.

```
Model.UserClassAverage = (
                from a in Db.averages
                join s in Db.subjects on a.subjectId equals s.id
                join c in Db.classes on s.classId equals c.id
                where (c.id == userClassId)
                || (c.classTeacherId == userID)
                select a.value 
                ).Average();
```

The problem is that whenever I create a user without a class I get an error saying

> The cast to value type 'double' failed because the materialized value is null

I was looking all over stack overflow for answers, and most of them apply to `SUM` instead of `AVERAGE`.

I tried to add the `?? 0` operand to the end of Average().. but it resulted in an error saying that **??** cant be applied to ints and doubles.

Is there any proper way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically the rules for `Average` are exactly the same as for the `Sum`.

My preferred way is to promote the non nullable type to nullable (in order to hit the corresponding method overload for nullable) and use the C# null-coalescing operator to convert the result back to non nullable:

```
...
select (double?)a.value 
).Average() ?? 0;
```

Comment: Yup, that did it! Thank you :D